# cannot access function within function in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

I need to know what I am doing wrong because I cannot call the internal functions show or hide?

```
(function()
{
    var Fresh = {
        notify:function()
        {
            var timeout = 20000;
            $("#notify-container div").get(0).id.substr(7,1) == "1" && (show(),setTimeout(hide(),timeout));
            var show = function ()
            {
                $("body").animate({marginTop: "2.5em"}, "fast", "linear");
                $("#notify-container div:eq(0)").fadeIn("slow");
            },
            hide = function()
            {
               $("#notify-container div").hide();
            }
        }//END notify
    }
    window.Fresh = Fresh;
})();
Fresh.notify();
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: move this line `$("#notify-container div").get(0).id.substr(7, 1) == "1" && (show(), setTimeout(hide(), timeout));` below the definition of show/hide.

Comment: thanks, that was it, I was contemplating it could not be that, could you put your answer in an "answer". Also do you know what it means if you put a return in the self execution function and return object  functions like return {show:function(){etc},hide:etc}

Comment: that does nothing, to my knowledge.

Comment: I saw that somewhere, anyway, I wanted to be able to write fresh.notify.showmessage()

Comment: @CoryKendall: Yes it does, Richard could have written this code like `var Fresh = (function(){...return {notify:functio(){...};})();` which would have assigned the object literal directly to the global variable Fresh, without the need for that extra line `window.Fresh = Fresh;`

Comment: @Richard, if you want to do that, you can. Functions are, essentially objects, and can have properties, I'll edit my answer to provide an example

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem good point, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If you wanted to be able to do something like: `Fresh.notify.showMessage()`, all you need to do is assign a property to the function `notify`:

```
var Fresh = {notify:function(){return 'notify called';}};
Fresh.notify.showMessage = function () { return this() + ' and showMessage, too!';};
Fresh.notify();//notify called
Fresh.notify.showMessage();//notify called and showMessage, too!
```

This will point to the function object here, and can be called as such (`this()` === `Fresh.notify();`). That's all there is too it.

There's a number of issues with this code. First of all: it's great that you're trying to use closures. But you're not using them to the fullest, if you don't mind my saying. For example: the `notify` method is packed with function declarations and jQuery selectors. This means that *each time* the method is invoked, new function objects will be created and the selectors will cause the dom to be searched time and time again. It's better to just keep the functions and the dom elements referenced in the closure scope:

```
(function()
{
    var body = $("body");
    var notifyDiv = $("#notify-container div")[0];
    var notifyDivEq0 = $("#notify-container div:eq(0)");
    var show = function ()
    {
        body.animate({marginTop: "2.5em"}, "fast", "linear");
        notifyDivEq0.fadeIn("slow");
    };
    var hide = function()
    {//notifyDiv is not a jQ object, just pass it to jQ again:
        $(notifyDiv).hide();
    };
    var timeout = 20000;
    var Fresh = {
        notify:function()
        {
            //this doesn't really make sense to me...
            //notifyDiv.id.substr(7,1) == "1" && (show(),setTimeout(hide,timeout));
            //I think this is what you want:
            if (notifyDiv.id.charAt(6) === '1')
            {
                show();
                setTimeout(hide,timeout);//pass function reference
                //setTimeout(hide(),timeout); calls return value of hide, which is undefined here
            }
        }//END notify
    }
    window.Fresh = Fresh;
})();
Fresh.notify();
```

It's hard to make suggestions in this case, though because, on its own, this code doesn't really make much sense. I'd suggest you set up [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see the code at work (or see the code fail :P)

Comment: thanks @Elias, using charAt is just a different way of getting the same thing isn't it?only a few characters shorter..

Comment: Yup, and it's X-browser compatible. If you don't care about older IE clients, you could even use `elem.id[6];`, both `charAt` and `[]`(array access) should also be _Very, very marginally_ faster

Comment: About setting up references, you are right...I did know about that, but this is just code in very early stages, where I change things a lot and test little lines of code if they actually are going to work..thanks for the input

Comment: I general I don't really care about IE, I get tired of reading things that need a workaround for ie. I just want to ban it al together. But, on the other hand, I am also not a very comercial enterprise

Comment: @Richard, sadly, all too many numbskull-dunce's still use IE. Saying I dislike IE would be an understatement, to say the least: I loathe it, with passion

Answer (score 2):

First, you're trying to use `show` value when it's not defined yet (though `show` variable does exist in that scope):

```
function test() {
  show(); // TypeError: show is not a function
  var show = function() { console.log(42); };
}
```

It's easily fixable with moving `var show` line above the point where it'll be called:

```
function test() {
  var show = function() { console.log(42); };
  show();
}
test(); // 42
```

... or if you define functions in more 'traditional' way (with `function show() { ... }` notation).

```
function test() {
  show();
  function show() { console.log(42); };
}
test(); // 42
```

Second, you should use this instead:

```
... && (show(), setTimeout(hide, timeout) );
```

... as it's the function name, and not the function result, that should be passed to `setTimeout` as the first argument.

Comment: Updated my answer. I wonder, btw, why do you have to define some local `show` and `hide` functions instead of using more generic ones, taking the element they should work on (`#notify-container` in this specific case) as an argument.

Comment: this was just sample code, I needed to know how to call functions, I fill in the rest of the logic later. I am still thinking how to go about it. Wanted to try things in a different way instead of heaving all kinds of isolated functions in my javascript file. I want to learn to write more plugin style

Answer (score 2):

You have to define show and hide before, also change the hide() as they said.
The result will be something like this:

```
(function()
{
    var Fresh = {
        notify:function()
        {
            var show = function()
            {
                $("body").animate({marginTop: "2.5em"}, "fast", "linear");
                $("#notify-container div:eq(0)").fadeIn("slow");
            },
            hide = function()
            {
               $("#notify-container div").hide();
            },
            timeout = 20000;
            $("#notify-container div").get(0).id.substr(7,1) == "1" && ( show(), setTimeout(hide,timeout) );

        }//END notify
    }
    window.Fresh = Fresh;
})();
Fresh.notify();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think order of calling show , hide is the matter . I have modified your code . It works fine . Please visit the link
http://jsfiddle.net/dzZe3/1/

Answer (score 0):

the
    (show(),setTimeout(hide(),timeout));

needs to at least be

```
(show(),setTimeout(function() {hide()},timeout));
```

or

```
(show(),setTimeout(hide,timeout));
```